# Computing Huffman Code Variance

Tags: huffman-code, variance

I have a HW question that involves me changing the way I do tie breaking and then asks me to compute the varience (the weights are probabilities).  I am wondering if anyone knows how to compute the varience. The main meat of the problem is not surrounded around this aspect so whoever negitived this question...thanks a lot

Here is the problem :

For data transmission purposes, it is often desirable to have a code with a minimum variance of the codeword lengths (among codes of the same average length). Compute the average (with the consideration of probability) and variance of the codeword length in two Huffman codes that result from a different tie breaking during a Huffman code construction for the following data:

Character             A B   C   D   E

Probability 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.4

I actually found my averages to be different...which seems incorrect

Comment: Whoever gave you a negative probably thought that your question seems vague and/or is asking us to do your homework for you. I one-upped the question again because I think it would benefit the community, but I would recommend 1) editing it to make it more specific by giving us a background about what language you are using and giving us solid numbers or code to work with and 2) bolding the actual questions you have in your description of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By picking different sets of the same lowest probability groups to combine, you can come up with three different bit length assignments.  They are all optimal, in that they all give exactly the same average bits per symbol.  However the three different codes each have a different range of bit lengths and will have different variances (with an 'a').

The variance is computed as the squares of the differences between the average bit length and the bit length of each symbol, and then a weighted sum of those by the probabilities.

(Note: your question is still not clear, since "I am wondering if anyone knows how to do this." could be referring to the changing the tie breaking, computing the variance, or both.  Nor is it clear which aspect is "this aspect".  You should think more about your exposition, especially the ambiguous usage of "this".)

Answer (score 0):

It appears they just wanted to settle ties a different way to show how average and variance  for condength is dependent on how ties are settled.  I just made up two different ways the priority ques would settle ties.